# Regex Replace exclude first and nth character

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to mask a `string` name with * (asterisks) and exclude both the first and nth (5th) characters.

Example:

> UserFirstName -> U****F*******

I managed to exclude the first character with `(?!^).`:

```cs
var regex = new Regex("(?!^).");
var result = regex.Replace(stringUserName, "*");
```

output:

> UserFirstName -> U************

How can I also exclude the character in the 5th position?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
(?!^)(?<!^.{4}).
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F!%5E%29%28%3F%3C!%5E.%7B4%7D%29.&i=UserFirstName&r=*)

**Pattern details**

- `(?!^)` - (it is equal to `(?<!^)` lookbehind that you may use instead) a negative lookahead that fails the position at the start of string
- `(?<!^.{4})` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current position, there are any four characters other than a newline char from the start of the string
- `.` - any single char other than a newline char.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/onIg3H):

```
string text = "UserFirstName";
int SkipIndex = 5;
string pattern = $@"(?!^)(?<!^.{{{SkipIndex-1}}}).";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "*"));
```

Output: `U***F********`

Answer (score 2):

Without Regex, extra explanation not required ;)

```
var text = "UserFirstName";
var skip = new[] { 0, 4 }.ToHashSet();

var masked = text.Select((c, index) => skip.Contains(index) ? c : '*').ToArray();
var output = new String(masked);

Console.WriteLine (output); // U***F********
```

[c# Demo](https://repl.it/repls/ForcefulWeeklyModule)